# react-beautiful-dnd onDragEnd not working on first drag

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd, react-beautiful-dnd

I am creating a project management kanban board using `react-beautiful-dnd`, I followed everything in the [video tutorial](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-course-introduction-beautiful-and-accessible-drag-and-drop-with-react-beautiful-dnd).

At first, it seems fine. But I noticed that when I drag an item and drop it, its not draggable anymore.

Here's what I got so far.

**App.js**

```
<div>
    <Kanban />
</div>
```

**initialData.js**

```
const initialData = {
tasks: {
    'task-1': { id: 'task-1', content: 'Take out the garbag'},
    'task-2': { id: 'task-2', content: 'Watch my favorite show'},
    'task-3': { id: 'task-3', content: 'Charge my phone'},
    'task-4': { id: 'task-4', content: 'Cook dinner'},
},
columns: {
    'column-1': {
        id: 'column-1',
        title: 'To do',
        taskIds: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']
    },
    'column-2': {
        id: 'column-2',
        title: 'In progress',
        taskIds: []
    },
    'column-3': {
        id: 'column-3',
        title: 'Done',
        taskIds: []
    },
},
// Facilitate reordering of the columns
columnOrder: ['column-1', 'column-2', 'column-3']
};

export default initialData;
```

**Kanban.js**

```
enter code hereimport React, { memo, useState } from 'react';
import { DragDropContext } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';
import '@atlaskit/css-reset';
import initialData from '../helpers/initialData';
import Column from './Column';

function Kanban() {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialData);
    
    const onDragEnd = result => {
        const { destination, source, draggableId } = result;

        console.log('rsu ', result);

        if (!destination)  return;

        if (
            destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
            destination.index === source.index
        ) return;

        const column = state.columns[source.droppableId];
        const newTaskIds = Array.from(column.taskIds);
        newTaskIds.splice(source.index, 1);
        newTaskIds.splice(destination.index, 0, draggableId);
        
        const newColumn = {
            ...column,
            taskIds: newTaskIds
        };
        const newState = {
            ...state,
            columns: {
                ...state.columns,
                [newColumn.id]: newColumn,
            },
        };

        console.log(newState);

        setState(newState);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <DragDropContext
                onDragEnd={onDragEnd}
            >
                {state.columnOrder.map(columnId => {
                    const column = state.columns[columnId];
                    const tasks = column.taskIds.map(taskId => state.tasks[taskId]);

                    return <Column key={column.id} column={column} tasks={tasks} />
                })}
            </DragDropContext>
        </>
    )
}

export default memo(Kanban);
```

**Column.js**

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Task from './Task';
import { Droppable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Container = styled.div`
    margin: 8px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 2px;
`;
const Title = styled.h3`
    padding: 8px;
`;
const TaskList = styled.div`
    padding: 8px;
`;

function Column({ column, tasks }) { 
    return (
        <Container>
            <Title>{column.title}</Title>
            
            <Droppable 
                key={`${column.id}-droppable`}
                droppableId={column.id} 
            >
                {(provided, snapshot) => (
                    <TaskList
                        ref={provided.innerRef}
                        {...provided.droppableProps}
                        
                    >
                        {tasks.map((task, index) => (
                            <Task key={task.id} task={task} index={index} />
                        ))}
                        {provided.placeholder}
                    </TaskList>
                )}
            </Droppable>

        </Container>
    )

}

export default memo(Column);
```

**Task.js**

```
import React, { memo } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Draggable } from 'react-beautiful-dnd';

const Container = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: ${props => (props.isDragging ? 'lightgreen' : 'white')};
`;

function Task({ task, index }) {
    return (    
        <Draggable
            draggableId={task.id}
            index={index}           
            key={`${task.id}-draggable`} 
        >
            {(provided, snapshot) => (
                <Container
                    ref={provided.innerRef}
                    {...provided.draggableProps}
                    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
                    isDragging={snapshot.isDragging}
                >
                    { task.content }
                </Container>
            )}
        </Draggable>
    )
}

export default memo(Task);
```

I noticed that the `onDragEnd` does not fire on first drag, maybe that's what's causing the problem.

I even changed `innerRef={provided.innerRef}` to `ref={provided.innerRef}`.

Can anyone help me? been stuck with this problem for almost a day already. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new to react DND and not 100% sure so here are a few potential options to try: (sorry I have to add this as an answer, I don't have the reputation to comment yet)

You could try setting your onDragEnd as a function rather than a constant and it might help.
In my app which is doing a similar thing I set as a function so it doesn't render on page load.

You could potentially do away with this section of code as well (although it won't fix your issue): It shouldn't matter if you reset state back as the original list order, it will do nothing.

```
if (
            destination.droppableId === source.droppableId &&
            destination.index === source.index
        ) return;
```

I suspect the columns array is what is really causing the problem. If you console 'column' from this code does it give an array of the current columns in order?
I suspect maybe this was meant to just be const column = state.columns?

```
const column = state.columns[source.droppableId];
        const newTaskIds = Array.from(column.taskIds);
```

Here's the code from my beautified dnd list if it helps:

```
function handleOnDragEnd(result) {
        if (!result.destination) return;
        const items = Array.from(widgets);
        const [reorderedItem] = items.splice(result.source.index, 1);
        items.splice(result.destination.index, 0, reorderedItem);
        setWidgets(items);
        //widgetCallback(items,_id);
    };


return(
<div>
<DragDropContext onDragEnd={handleOnDragEnd}>
                            <Droppable droppableId={page.pageTag}>
                                {(provided) => (
                                    <div className={classes.cardBoard} {...provided.droppableProps} ref={provided.innerRef}>
                                        {(widgets == undefined || widgets == [] || (pageZoomFactor<0.5 && !pageExpanded)) ? <div/> : widgets.map((widget, index) => {
                                            widget = Object.assign(widget, {cardExpanded: pageExpanded})
                                            return (
                                                <Draggable 
                                                    key={widget._id} 
                                                    draggableId={widget._id == undefined ? "fakeID" : widget._id} 
                                                    index={index} 
                                                    className={classes.widget} 
                                                >
                                                    {(provided) => (
                                                        <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.draggableProps} {...provided.dragHandleProps}>
                                                            <Widget widgetProp={widget} pageID={_id} index={index} changeWidgetCallback={handleChangeWidgetCallback} pageZoomFactor={pageZoomFactor}/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    )}
                                                </Draggable>
                                            );
                                        })}
                                        {provided.placeholder}
                                    </div>
                                )}
                            </Droppable>
                        </DragDropContext>
</div>
```